# How to write comparative sentences?

Tags: grammar, comparatives

I have some problem in comparative sentence. For example:

> In lower layer PS=10%
>
> In upper layer PS=5%

For this I wrote the sentence as below:

> 1. In lower layer PS is greater than upper layer.
> 2. In lower layer PS is greater than that in the upper layer.

Grammatically, which sentence is correct? I am writing this sentence for a scientific article.

Comment: The second is correct. But don't forget you need the definite article - "In the lower layer..."

Comment: @WS2 thanks for guidance. but I do not understand "But don't forget you need the definite article - "In the lower layer..." –" what this mean?

Comment: In THE lower layer PS is greater than in the upper layer.

Comment: In addition to inserting "the" in the second sentence (as WS2 has told you), I would delete "that".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the sentences seem fine. The first sentence is more condensed form of the second one. Although, given that these sentences are meant for a scientific article. You can go for the following as well.

"In the lower layer PS is 10%, whereas in the upper layer it's only 5%"

Hope it helps